# When downloading a site, why does Filezilla ask about overwrites?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Sometimes when I download a fresh instance of a website (for backup purposes), Filezilla will ask me if I want to overwrite a file. I'm downloading the hierarchy straight from the FTP, I've never downloaded it before, so how could there possibly be 2 files with the same name in the same place? Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: lol sounds like a bug

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? Or any other details? Log file? Platform (both local and remote)? Anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually happens if transfers are prematurally interupted by a firewall/router/security scanner/bad connection etc. etc. etc. On a transfer retry, Filezilla finds the already created file and asks what to do with it.

You must check every software and device the traffic flows through. As there are so many possible causes I can't give a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

'cause Linux (I image is a Linux hosting) for file name is case sensitive, "info.txt" is different from "INFO.TXT" and different from "Info.txt". Windows is not case sensitive about file name so it find more than one file with the same name in the same directory.
Filezilla can do nothing about that.